# Node.js hostname/IP doesnt match certificates altnames

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, coffeescript

I'm writing some node code to do a server side login to Facebook.  I'm pretty close to having it completely functioning, but I am having troubles requesting the auth_code.
I'm thinking it might have something to do with the facebook app setting `Site URL` but nothing I've tried has worked.
I'm using node version 0.8.14.

Here is the code I do my request in:

```
options =
    host: 'graph.facebook.com'
    port: 443
    path: "/oauth/access_token?" + qs.stringify(
        client_id:     app_id
        redirect_uri:  my_url
        client_secret: app_secret
        code:          vars.code)

https.get(options, (face_res)->
    console.log face_res
)
```

In the `face_res` I get a couple of objects like this:

```
authorizationError: 'Hostname/IP doesn\'t match certificate\'s altnames'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Looks like the question got prematurely submitted

Comment: What version of Node.js are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok funny thing is the error I was getting was completely irrelevant.  As soon as I added a `request.on("data", function(data){})` event listener I was able to see that I was receiving the `auth_token` as expected.