# Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames node.js

Tags: nodemailer

i want tom send email from my application using nodemailer , my code looks like this :

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
          pool: true,
        host: 'smtp.myemailserver.com',
        port: 587,
        auth: {
            user: 'user@myDomain.com',
            pass: '******'
        }
}));
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'user@myDomain.com',
    to: 'user2@gmail.com',
    subject: 'test ',
    text: 'Hello world ',
    html: '<b>Hello world </b>'
    };

smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
       console.log(error);
    }else{
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

but i get error that i can't figure out  :

```
 [Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: smtp.myemailserver.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:secure.emailsrvr.com, DNS:www.secure.myemailserver.com"]
      reason: 'Host: smtp.myemailserverr.com. is not in the cert\'s altnames: DNS:secure.myemailserver.com, DNS:www.myemailserver.com',
      host: 'smtp.myemailserver.com.',
      cert: 
       { subject: { OU: [Object], CN: 'secure.myemailserver.com' },
         issuer: 
          { C: 'GB',
            ST: 'Greater Manchester',
            L: 'Salford',
            O: 'COMODO CA Limited',
            CN: 'COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA' },
         subjectaltname: 'DNS:secure.emailsrvr.com, DNS:www.secure.myemailserver.com',
         infoAccess: { 'CA Issuers - URI': [Object], 'OCSP - URI': [Object] }
```

i tried to add

```
tls { 
rejectUnauthorized: false 
}
```

to email option but that causes blocking my email , so please any help

Comment: what does it mean "blocking my email" ? Please provide the log with the tls option set as you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending emails with nodemailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099582/sending-emails-with-nodemailer)

Answer (score 25):

Not sure you're missing the colon in your code like in your question, but it should be:

```
tls: { 
    rejectUnauthorized: false 
}
```

In my experience, that's all you need to get around cert name mismatches. The whole transport options should look like this:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    pool: true,
    host: 'smtp.myemailserver.com',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: 'user@myDomain.com',
        pass: '******'
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
```

Also keep in mind this leaves you [vulnerable to MITM attacks on SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16311147/4068278).

Comment: getting error response
:
"535 Incorrect authentication data"

Comment: HTTP 535 means something is wrong with your authentication method. Perhaps incorrect account credentials?