# TLS what exactly does 'rejectUnauthorized' mean for me?

Tags: node.js, ssl

So, I was having an issue earlier today where my client, written in `node`, was barfing because the server I was connecting to used self signed certs. So, I went and added the option `rejectUnauthorized: false` to my `tls.connect` command like any unwitting developer would do.

My question is now, what the hell does this mean for me? Is my TLS connection just a vanilla TCP connection that can also possibly be a TLS connection? Is writing this as a TLS stream totally useless?

More importantly, that server, you know the one with the self-signed certs? Is my stream between here and there actually encrypted?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_port_host_options_callback):

- `rejectUnauthorized`: If `true`, the server certificate is verified against the list of supplied CAs. An `error` event is emitted if verification fails; `err.code` contains the OpenSSL error code. Default: `true`.

Since you're using self-signed certificates, obviously there won't be a match with the built-in CAs, so by default the connection would be rejected because it cannot verify the server is who they say they are.

By setting `rejectUnauthorized: false`, you're saying "I don't care if I can't verify the server's identity." Obviously this is not a good solution as it leaves you vulnerable to MITM attacks.

A better solution for self-signed certificates is to set the appropriate `ca` value to your custom CA when connecting client-side. Also, make sure your `host` value matches that of the Common Name of the server's self-signed certificate. For example:

```
var socket = tls.connect({
  host: 'MyTLSServer',
  port: 1337,
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('CA.pem') ],
}, function() {
  // Connected!
});

// ...
```

No matter if you use `rejectUnauthorized: false` or set `ca`, the connection is encrypted.

Comment: Node was throwing the error: 'SELF SIGNED CERT IN CHAIN'. Is there a better way to get around that for self signeds? Could the host/CN be an IP address?

Comment: I handled it using 'NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0' flag. It is not the correct way to do it but workd for developemnt enviroment

Comment: The better way and the correct way was included in the answer. It is the line that starts with `ca:`