# KafkaJS producer ssl certificates

Tags: node.js, ssl, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I'm writing a NodeJS Kafka producer with KafkaJS and having trouble understanding how to get the required SSL certificates in order to connect to the Kafka using the SASL-SSL connection.
In the KafkaJS documentation there is this configuration for SSL:

```
ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('/my/custom/ca.crt', 'utf-8')],
    key: fs.readFileSync('/my/custom/client-key.pem', 'utf-8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/my/custom/client-cert.pem', 'utf-8')
  },
```

With which I have problem because I don't know how/what certificates I should provide to it.

Do I need to provide all three props (ca, key and cert) ?? If so how to obtain them? We have Kafka cluster configured like so [Confluent Security Tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/current/security/security_tutorial.html)
Do I have to decode keystore or something in order to obtain proper certs for my KafkaJS 
producer? I have a bare understanding of all of this.

Answer (score 2):

Does your broker enforce client authentication? If yes, then you will need `key` and `cert`. If your client is running on 'standard' computer, then most well known CA will already be present e.g. at `/etc/ssl/certs`. In such a case, you will *only* need `ssl : true`. If you are using a self-signed certificate *but not* client authentication, then `ca` needs to be provided.

So, here are your options.

### Client authentication

If CA is self-signed, then add `ca` also (see below).

```js
ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/my/custom/client-key.pem', 'utf-8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/my/custom/client-cert.pem', 'utf-8')
  }
```

### Self-signed certificate

```js
ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('/my/custom/ca.crt', 'utf-8')]
  }
```

The `rejectUnauthorized : false` will *not* check against known CA.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31861109/919480) for more information.