# Heroku Postgres: "psql: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host"

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli, postgres-10

There are a number of Heroku CLI Postgres commands that all return the same error. For example:

```
$ heroku pg:bloat
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "...", user "...", database "...", SSL off
```

At least one of these commands has worked in the past, but does not now.

The database appears to be working fine otherwise. I can access it via my application's interfaces.

I do not see a way to toggle SSL in the Heroku Postgres dashboard. What could be causing this and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that commands like `heroku pg:bloat` use the local installation of Postgres and `psql` under the hood. I recompiled my Postgres installation with ssl support (`--with-openssl`) and everything worked.

Comment: When installing Postgres with **asdf-vm**, you can add a file `~/.asdf-postgres-configure-options` with the content `export POSTGRES_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--with-openssl"`. This will then be used during `asdf install`. See [here](https://github.com/smashedtoatoms/asdf-postgres/pull/17).

Answer (score 29):

I got the error while connecting to **Postgres** from an external application. The fix is relative to the language that you use. In **Java** you need to chain the `?sslmode=require` to query string, in **NodeJS** (my situation) you should add `rejectUnauthorized: false` as following -

```
const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
```

Refer to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql for more details.

> Enjoy!

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work with pg-promise in Node.js?

Answer (score 13):

I solved it by setting PGSSLMODE on Heroku to require.  This tells Postres to default to SSL.  On the command line this can be done via the following command.

```
heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=require
```

Comment: this resulted in an error for me 'Error: self signed certificate' any ideas why?

Comment: This one doesn't fix my issue with Python

Answer (score 7):

The error basically says that you are trying to connect to a database instance without using SSL connection, but the server is setup to reject connection without SSL connection.

[pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file resides in the server, and contains details of the allowed connections. In your case there's no matching record to be found in the file with the given details(under non-ssl connection).

You can fix this by forcing the connection to be follow SSL protocol. As Raj already mentioned, you need to modify your connection string to include the 'sslmode=require'. [Here's](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#heroku-postgres-ssl) a heroku documentation regarding the same. Check out the 'external connections' block in the doc.

Comment: I'm not able to pass a string to the Heroku command, though that did fix the issue when I passed the connection string to my local `psql` command.

Answer (score 6):

Adding `ssl option` in database configs fixed this issue on my end:

If you are using sequelize as your ORM

```
const config = {
  ...
  production: {
    use_env_variable: 'DATABASE_URL',
    dialect: 'postgresql',
    logging: false,
        dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {      /* <----- Add SSL option */
        require: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false 
      }
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

If you are not using any ORM:

```
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString:DATABASE_URL ,
  ssl: {    /* <----- Add SSL option */
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `sslmode=require` in your connections string. An example for when the JDBC driver is:

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + 
dbUri.getPath() + "?sslmode=require";
```

You can always toggle the `ssl_mode` in the config vars but I would suggest doing it in the connection string.

Answer (score 4):

This works for Nodejs. Specify the PGSSLMODE config var: **heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify** you can do that through a terminal with the Heroku CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I think on Heroku the SSL is not `disabled` but `require`, which can be the reason for this error.

Answer (score 1):

This helped resolve the issue in my case. Adding the ***ssl*** property in config.json (Sequelize)

```js
{
  "production": {
    "ssl": {
      "require": true,
      "rejectUnauthorized": false
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31862256/4660514), setting `rejectUnauthorized: false` is a bad idea because it allows you to create non-encrypted connections to your database and can, thus, expose you to MITM attack (man-in-the-middle attacks).

A better solution is to give your Postgre client the CA that you want it to use. In your case it might be a Heroku CA, but in my case it was a CA used by AWS RDS for the North Virginia region (us-east-1). I downloaded the CA from [this AWS page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html), placed it in the same directory as the file I wanted to use to create a connection and then modified my config to:

```
{
  ...
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      require: true,
      ca: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/us-east-1-bundle.pem`),
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sequelize as your ORM this is the configuration for the connection needed to solve this problem. Edit your database file (db.js): As explained in [this answer](https://help.heroku.com/QD1AIH8R/how-do-i-use-sequelize-to-connect-to-heroku-postgres)  by Heroku.

```
var connection = process.env.DATABASE_URL
isProduction ? connection  : connection = connectionString;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(connection,{
      logging: false,   //Loging disabled
      dialectOptions: {
        ssl:{
          require:true,
          rejectUnauthorized: false
        } 
      }
  });
  try {
      sequelize.authenticate();
      console.log('Database connected successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
    }
```

also edit your config.json file as explained [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/)

Answer (score -1):

Appending `?sslmode=require` to the connection URL worked for me.

Comment: This is already an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60050861/2317928