# Error 503 when calling API from Heroku (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, api, heroku, http-status-code-503

The Api is working good in development but then at Heroku is not and I get 503 Service Unavailable. I was looking the logs but couldn't figure out anything. I think that the problem is with the connection with the database but I don't know. I can provide more information if needed.

```
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const pool = require('./db');
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
}

app.get('/names/date/:asc', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const ascDsc = req.params.asc;
    const query =
      ascDsc === 'ASC'
        ? 'SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY u_id ASC'
        : 'SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY u_id DESC';
    const results = await pool.query(query);
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      results: results.rows.length,
      data: results.rows,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build/index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is starting on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I am calling the Api with axios

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `/names/${page}/${ascDsc ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'}`
        );
        setAllNames(response.data.data);
        setTotalNames(response.data.results);
        setTotalPersons(
          response.data.data.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next.amount, 0)
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [page, ascDsc, deleteRefresh, addRefresh]);
```

and I have set in the package.json

`"proxy":"http://localhost:5000"`

Logs:

````
2021-01-23T19:07:50.723952+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.d2e70d9d.chunk.js.map" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=69178607-7f88-44cd-84f5-796374e4b8c5 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=20267 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:07:50.891616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css.map" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=cffee92d-1ab3-406b-927e-3afa4d5c98e8 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=1238 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:07:59.985044+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:08:01.258231+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:08:02.496326+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:08:03.103884+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:08:06.251153+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/date/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=6f07c270-c64b-4c85-b8e5-294dee6d3238 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=64ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:08:11.567934+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/date/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=58e93e41-0c07-4e30-a7b9-538bad625e94 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:08:29.962406+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/names" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=bfd22550-3034-4ebb-a627-8353c757ae89 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:08:31.252443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/names" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=8946f047-02b4-4545-83ba-bd55867f5149 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:08:32.473324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/names" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=6fd7643e-dfd5-44a2-8a20-8ac76f6bb8cc fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:08:33.077888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/names" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=7a82edfc-a459-48f7-9e49-be5ea1405c96 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:09:51.735698+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:10:21.693520+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/amount/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=8020b5d6-225b-4109-ba5c-52177c769475 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=14ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:10:53.845295+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:11:23.823725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/amount/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=2c235195-a5da-415e-b9a0-1173e3de08d1 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:14:55.267208+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:15:25.246545+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/alpha/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=25d4c475-233c-4cc0-a7b0-7acef45864d9 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:15:34.418815+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:15:53.687067+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:16:04.407563+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/alpha/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=d893c7d6-5926-4a68-8fb7-8efbaaab428b fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:16:23.672253+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/alpha/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=a6b45982-8e57-4fde-82a8-1b38d2b8b764 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2021-01-23T19:27:12.145775+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:27:14.348004+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:27:16.881014+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=cb56c0f3-67c3-4a37-80c8-363d4bffd30a fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=2535 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:17.147741+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=05a53023-d922-4e95-8df7-513c660f46c1 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=881 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:17.346886+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.ec471818.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com 
request_id=dc30a6c2-4ca7-490d-b0a9-76399d97fdbf fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=200 bytes=352865 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:17.413224+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.d2e70d9d.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=c75340d1-8c22-47ea-8f30-72e5d3a9f73c fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=7860 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:17.429188+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css.map" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=81f18b77-c10e-4374-8ac3-0e3f6b63da2c fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=1238 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:18.386656+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.d2e70d9d.chunk.js.map" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=acfc4c34-565a-4c5f-b5d8-0d3eb7996e9a fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=20267 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:18.412640+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:27:18.442926+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.ec471818.chunk.js.map" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=19d5a813-25c6-494e-8a6f-3cefe4d69969 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=65ms status=200 bytes=1413000 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:18.459254+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=472b222e-ab26-4127-b0b9-d2b67fa1322e fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=4179 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:19.047911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=f1aacd47-1b24-4e1d-90f5-35e234942227 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=819 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:19.213569+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=7d2e055c-67c7-4961-9e4c-eaaeb0250a5a fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=5654 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:37.364721+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:27:42.127360+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/amount/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=575460d9-cab4-4002-b305-996c68ab8d1c fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:44.144473+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/date/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=9518cd40-f2a7-4540-8370-f17e44417dd9 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:27:48.406405+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/date/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=a98c37db-0ff3-49e7-84e5-3b811621b7ac fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:28:07.355517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/amount/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=b31a4e27-1a49-4924-9aa2-3184aefdf70c fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30002ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:03.846509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=14f7d352-4d6d-44b7-8bb7-228a2a9a74b8 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:04.066269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=a9c6e7f6-6953-4a11-ad4f-e0362b2a88e6 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:04.079075+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.ec471818.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com 
request_id=0792fd6b-3cc3-41bd-adcb-28087202bf06 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https   
2021-01-23T19:29:04.221684+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.d2e70d9d.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=416612fe-99d1-404d-9409-733c6fd4388f fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https2021-01-23T19:29:04.709668+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:29:04.998142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=1714d8bb-9dcf-4e27-9fca-a2fddb8c9083 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:05.157212+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=e08d6379-5aa9-4c63-a311-ec2b927ade1d fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:07.588544+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:29:08.520784+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:29:09.938096+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=7674284a-4e8f-4052-8948-8d1f9e64ad1d fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:10.241355+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=eb3044ce-3ae8-495d-ae53-1ef19fd7d488 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:10.286484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.d2e70d9d.chunk.js.map" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=d722fb68-d2c0-488b-8177-90e2228f8e44 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=20267 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:10.321868+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.ec471818.chunk.js.map" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=e20156f4-b39f-4fe0-b866-ebde9242262a fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=43ms status=200 bytes=1413000 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:10.427776+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css.map" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=45b6a576-55ad-48e3-9c29-8994e0f5d656 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=1238 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:17.178071+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:29:34.689520+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/date/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=02e8feb7-6d03-4b84-a0ad-37acdca020bb fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:37.581679+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/alpha/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=de6cb3d3-d0ef-423d-a691-bfd619efbea4 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:38.516097+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/amount/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=50c3917b-8f24-4c69-b815-a05587790e70 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:29:47.174409+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/date/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=bb611890-e0ee-484f-8769-b2768a692a3f fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:33:47.420073+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=311768e7-b035-4581-9603-381f1d98f950 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:33:47.652420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=ab65a62e-c40b-402a-9629-d37b27942f7c fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:33:47.658485+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.ec471818.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com 
request_id=5ceb9f26-a881-403e-8a1d-d2e7a40c45a5 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https   
2021-01-23T19:33:47.667278+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.d2e70d9d.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=3763dd05-610f-412e-a1a7-ed6a05408ba8 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https2021-01-23T19:33:48.053305+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:33:48.492479+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=0f45b0be-5d7c-46db-bef6-1d0233f6d71d fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:33:48.654327+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=5f7a9c86-e2ed-4a5b-8deb-5366ed5ddcdd fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:34:18.033285+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/date/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=935ad4a7-bcc3-4486-9c71-aa13bfe70e83 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:37:03.205695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=cfa91b7b-a223-41d1-b437-5af9b0d95cd3 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:37:03.425300+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=2d82ad6e-5d13-40cc-8f1e-5dad06c3139d fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:37:03.427421+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.ec471818.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com 
request_id=823f2374-29f1-46ef-98a1-d5b3ffbfa4bf fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https   
2021-01-23T19:37:03.588120+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.d2e70d9d.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=ef1e73ae-d263-4efe-bff6-2f910c88ae91 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https2021-01-23T19:37:04.007976+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:37:04.484960+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=deeff89d-f0c7-4be0-a73b-86a1a047d5fb fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:37:04.644919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=9500b88a-6ff6-45c6-a324-8cc81addc0e5 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:37:34.003687+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/date/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=e8385655-1c16-4b4e-9937-f8c2a95d8816 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30003ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:48:28.367052+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=f3f4ce21-5c22-4257-99b2-939a704a6752 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:48:28.591231+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.d2e70d9d.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=6994cb75-1d1a-4c62-91e6-023d45c556a3 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https2021-01-23T19:48:28.593526+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=ecb9dbf4-0f23-4309-ab66-4902a82c733a fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:48:28.595999+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.ec471818.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com 
request_id=7eb7d149-47df-4afb-98dc-7ebb1d4845b2 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https   
2021-01-23T19:48:28.899533+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=33001334-6bda-4117-b132-a92f0ff2b000 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=4179 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:48:28.904414+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:48:29.352775+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=651d6f02-5973-4f40-b926-52c6b311e036 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:48:29.525471+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=c688c1d7-ad80-4966-9fbc-c1e38336e0b2 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:48:29.633846+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=959fe449-1729-4677-a19d-47a6a88c8ef1 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:48:29.634691+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=b6b7c883-63a9-491b-99cf-0a375f0b285b fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:48:29.720034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.ec471818.chunk.js.map" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=58da7a9f-2761-4634-88de-46cc961ecba0 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=1413000 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:48:29.795130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.d2e70d9d.chunk.js.map" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=b046d679-d2ba-4a87-8364-5d72a8e1bbbb fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=20267 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:48:30.019693+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css.map" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=3ccb182a-7a12-4c4d-a732-61942a7a86ad fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=1238 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:48:35.987618+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T19:48:58.896439+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/date/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=f8fcbdd1-bcdd-49df-a53d-676ffe81b442 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T19:49:05.979375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/alpha/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=15bb91f0-5365-41d6-bef8-63c0c6f7eba7 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-01-23T20:06:27.597524+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=c6e9db07-7449-4c5f-8c9d-19e633d4eb39 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T20:06:27.817430+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.ddfd552e.chunk.css" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=eb8aa6eb-ebcc-40d9-8cf5-d7c2b6abb10e fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T20:06:27.820575+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.d2e70d9d.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=02a2fe75-cb37-4e18-8c9e-f2b7d7d2632d fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https2021-01-23T20:06:27.828706+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.ec471818.chunk.js" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com 
request_id=95c6e7ef-ceef-4ee2-aaba-c5dda20159e0 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https   
2021-01-23T20:06:28.174177+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.173.176", user "spyaxnccecsysq", database "de92cnoh3sef8j", SSL off
2021-01-23T20:06:28.638284+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=0c228437-1585-4344-b122-05a624a974e6 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-01-23T20:06:28.802181+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=c66381ab-0749-4131-97df-3122b834ed9a fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2021-01-23T20:06:58.153795+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/names/date/ASC" host=solita-academy.herokuapp.com request_id=17326b49-8c90-454d-963e-d74ef9d5deb7 fwd="37.33.172.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https```
````

Comment: Ok so this is how I fixed the problem ** no pg_hba.conf entry for host
**  
For NodeJS:

 `const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});`

I found the answer from here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048669/heroku-postgres-psql-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)