# "FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry" error from postgres using db-migrate in Node on Heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

This is [background on the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64334917/4616147)

The difference in this situation is that the pg client is constructed via `db-migrate`.  In the process of upgrading to Node 14, in order to resolve compiler warnings, npm packages were updated as follows:

```
    "db-migrate": "^0.11.12",
    "db-migrate-pg": "^1.2.2",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
```

which caused deployment to heroku to now fail with this error:

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "...", user "...", database "...", SSL off
```

From the background, the postgres client ([pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)) must be changed to establish its connection using `ssl = { rejectUnauthorized: false }`.  However, the client is created not directly but via `db-migrate`.

We are not using the documented command-line form of `db-migrate`, but instead have a wrapper migration script.  This script does not invoke the command-line `db-migrate` but instead calls `DBMigrate.getInstance(true, options);`, where those options are programmatically generated per-environment.  Thus we circumvent the documented file-based configuration of `db-migrate`.

Per [the `db-migrate` docs](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting%20Started/configuration/#database_url), `DATABASE_URL` was intended for use with heroku but that assumes a command-line invocation of `db-migrate` will honor the environment variable and then ignore (non .rc-) file-based configuration.  Since we have the wrapper script, we instead depend on `DATABASE_URL` via another [documented `db-migrate` mechanism](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting%20Started/configuration/#configuration):

> Note that if the settings for an environment are represented by a single string that string will be parsed as a database URL.

Thus we use this programmatic configuration generated in our wrapper script:

```
const options = {
  env: "your_env_name_here",
  config: {
    your_env_name_here: process.env.DATABASE_URL
  },
};
const dbmigrate = DBMigrate.getInstance(true, options);
```

How do I specify the required ssl configuration *through* `db-migrate` using `DATABASE_URL`?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that allowing `db-migrate` to parse our heroku-provided `DATABASE_URL` was itself interfering with heroku's infrastructural choices requiring `ssl = { rejectUnauthorized: false }` to begin with, which cannot be provided by that URL alone.  The [pg-connection-string library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-connection-string) will do this for you, and the code snippet below translates that parsed URL to `db-migrate`'s long-form but including the necessary heroku ssl configuration.

```
const parse = require('pg-connection-string').parse;
const r = parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
const options = {
  env: "your_env_name_here",
  config: {
    your_env_name_here: {
      driver: "pg",
      user: r.user,
      password: r.password,
      host: r.host,
      database: r.database,
      port: r.port,
      ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    },
  },
};
const dbmigrate = DBMigrate.getInstance(true, options);
```

This re-enabled our heroku deploy using Node 14 and updated npm libraries related to postgres and db-migrate.