# Configure Atom - Remote FTP with a Explicit FTP over TLS (FTPES)

Tags: ftp, atom-editor, ftps

I'm trying to connect my Atom to a Hostek hosting by FTP ... and their FTP connections will require Explicit FTP over TLS (FTPES).

```
{
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "host": "ftp.mysite.com",
    "port": 21,
    "user": "myuser",
    "pass": "**********",
    "promptForPass": false,
    "remote": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "secureOptions": null,
    "connTimeout": 10000,
    "pasvTimeout": 10000,
    "keepalive": 10000,
    "watch": []
}
```

Comment: What part of the [documentation of the FTP/FTPS configuration options](https://atom.io/packages/remote-ftp)  don't you understand? What did your try and which errors did you got?

Comment: Seems like you would need to set `"secure": true` or `"secure": "control"`, at the very least...

Comment: On FTP client I use "FTP with TLS/SSL" but here I don't know how define this protocol. Now I'm having the error: (Remote FTP: Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: ftp.mysite.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.hostek.com, DNS:hostek.com")

Answer (score 4):

Probably late, but you'll want to use `"secure": "control"`.

Now, for the cert verification error, you'll need to add:

```
"secureOptions" : {
  "rejectUnauthorized": false
}
```

So the connection does not fail when cert verification does. **This may introduce security risks**: [Node.js Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262986/node-js-hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altnames#answer-16311147)

Comment: Thanks, this should be the answer