# Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames:

Tags: node.js, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I am using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) as an HTTP client for node.js

I am using a proxy on localhost and port 8888 so I can sniff network traffic with [Charles Proxy](http://charlesproxy.com) for debugging.

```
 axios.get(`http://example.com',
           { proxy: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 8888 })
    .then(result => { // })
    .catch(error => { console.log(error) })
```

With this configuration, I often receive this error message:

> Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames:

I read here:
[Node.js Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262986/node-js-hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altnames)
that  I have to configure node.js like this to disable security checks:

```
{ rejectUnauthorized : false }
```

My question is how and where exactly do I make that configuration?

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if you solve that. I hope you did. If not, for a known server as it is not safe to do that:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;
```

You can put this code in the file that is calling that server.