# Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames [Meteor JS Email]

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts

> Using Meteor 1.5 with `email` package installed.

I have tried both `smtps` and `smtps`, both are not working for me. Any suggestions that why I am facing this error?

**ERROR LOG:**

```
I20170719-19:56:59.430(5.5)? Exception while invoking method 'forgotPassword' Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: mail.xyz.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:something.something.in, DNS:www.something.something.in"
I20170719-19:56:59.432(5.5)?     at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.5.0\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:449:15)
I20170719-19:56:59.435(5.5)?     at Mail._syncSendMail (packages\meteor.js:213:24)
I20170719-19:56:59.437(5.5)?     at smtpSend (packages\email.js:110:13)
I20170719-19:56:59.443(5.5)?     at Object.Email.send (packages\email.js:168:5)
I20170719-19:56:59.447(5.5)?     at AccountsServer.Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:614:9)
I20170719-19:56:59.451(5.5)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.forgotPassword (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:546:12)
I20170719-19:56:59.461(5.5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1737:12)
I20170719-19:56:59.466(5.5)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:719:19
I20170719-19:56:59.468(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages\meteor.js:1122:17)
I20170719-19:56:59.476(5.5)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:717:40
I20170719-19:56:59.478(5.5)?     - - - - -
I20170719-19:56:59.480(5.5)?     at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:205:17)
I20170719-19:56:59.481(5.5)?     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1071:29)

I20170719-19:56:59.484(5.5)?     at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
I20170719-19:56:59.486(5.5)?     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
I20170719-19:56:59.487(5.5)?     at TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:623:8)
I20170719-19:56:59.494(5.5)?     at TLSWrap.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.ssl.onnewsession.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:453:38)
```

My SMTP settings are as below;

```
smtp = {
    username: 'info@xyz.com',
    password: 'info@2017',
    server:   'mail.xyz.com',
    port: 465,
    rejectUnauthorized : false
  }

process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtps://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that with newer version of Node (see link: [Node.js Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262986/node-js-hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altnames) ) domains are being tested.

The correct "fix" is to get the server corrected, a (somewhat dangerous) fix is to tell Node to reject Unauthorized, which you tried to do, however the smtp object in your source get's thrown away and is never passed to Meteor.

Try adding the following:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;
```

right after

```
process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtps://' + ...
```

(Note: this suggestion is derived from: ([Unable to verify leaf signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082893/unable-to-verify-leaf-signature#20100521)) but I have tested that this resolves the problem).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this and let you know.

Comment: It Worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification