# SSL Termination at CloudFront, reverse proxy to ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront

I'm attempting to terminate SSL at CF, and send http to ELB.

When I changed the `Origin Protocol Policy` to `HTTP Only`, when I make an https request, it is returning a `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` error.

What are the proper settings for the Cloudfront distribution to perform SSL termination at CF, and forward to the ELB?

My current settings are:

`Origin Domain Name`: a-xxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

`Origin Protocol Policy`: `http-only`

When I had `match-viewer`, http was working, and of course https was not. I'm intentionally am not trying to have the same cert in 2 places, and want to terminate at CF like so:

`https -> CF -> http -> ELB`

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52157174/549372

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have pointed a domain name at CloudFront but you didn't set the Alternate Domain Name for the distribution to that hostname.

Comment: yep! Michael you are right. Thank you. I thought for some reason that alias would be for additional names. This was the fix!