# NodeJS Express reverse proxy TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl, http-proxy

I have a reverse proxy on my endpoint like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var serverOne = 'https://idena.navarra.es/ogc/wms?';

app.all('/idena', function (req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverOne});
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Working!');
});
```

When a request to `/idena` is received, the server throws an exception like this:

> Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match
> certificate's altnames: Host: localhost. is not in the cert's
> altnames: DNS:idena.navarra.es, DNS:[www.idena.navarra.es](http://www.idena.navarra.es)
> at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:235:17)
> at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1061:27)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
> at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:633:8)

How can I solve this? Guess is due to `https` but no idea of how to avoid that, thanks!

Comment: Check [**how to use https**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy#using-https) with this package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262986/node-js-hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altnames)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although the error is about mismatching SSL certificate and domain names, in http-proxy module, the error often manifests when your server is HTTP and the Target is HTTPS.

You can avoid this error through the change  `changeOrigin` flag.

> ```
> const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
>
> proxy.web(req, res, {
>   changeOrigin: true,
>   target: https://example.com:3000,
> });
> ```
>
> In case your server is HTTPS and target one is HTTPS as well, you
>   should include SSL certificate
>
> ```
> httpProxy.createServer({
>   ssl: {
>     key: fs.readFileSync('valid-ssl-key.pem', 'utf8'),
>     cert: fs.readFileSync('valid-ssl-cert.pem', 'utf8')
>   },
>   target: 'https://example.com:3000',
>   secure: true
> }).listen(443);
> ```

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262986/node-js-hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altnames) question.