# How to proxy requests from vercel Next.Js API to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, proxy, next.js, vercel

```js
// next js - [...api]

import httpProxy from "http-proxy";
const BLOG_SERVER = process.env.BLOG_SERVER; // https://example.com
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
}

export default async function Api(req, res) {
    const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
    proxy.web(req, res, {
      target: BLOG_SERVER
    });
    proxy.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log(e)
    });
}
```

The `BLOG_SERVER` has been hosted at heroku and `next.js` website has been hosted at `vercel`.

When i looked at the `next.js` server logs, then the following are printed.

[image: vercel-logs]

#### How can i solve this??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS Express reverse proxy TLS\_CERT\_ALTNAME\_INVALID error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766108/nodejs-express-reverse-proxy-tls-cert-altname-invalid-error)

Comment: No, now i am getting this error 
```js
[POST] /api/do/auth/sign-up
19:57:38:74
Function Status:
None
Edge Status:
504
Duration:
10010.54 ms
Init Duration:
N/A
Memory Used:
32 MB
ID:
hd5x2-1628951258206-6d7a91672cec
User Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36
{ msg: 'Got the request...' }
2021-08-14T14:27:48.881Z b242cc90-828c-4368-82fd-475ef4db2d98 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds
```