# mailu docker - how to include container id to let's encrypt certificate?

Tags: docker, meteor, lets-encrypt

I'm searching now for hours threw the internet but found nothing what would suit my case.

I have a mailu docker installed on my server and I want to send emails from my meteor application threw this container.

I set my MAIL_URL variable like `process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@DOCKER-IP:465';` and this is working when I use also the global variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0` but I don't want to use it, because of security reasons.

When I send emails from my meteor app on my laptop and using my email server mail.foo.com instead of the docker-id like `smtps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@mail.foo.com:465` then it also works. So from outside I have no problem but when I'm on the server I can't use localhost like `smtps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:465` or `smtps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@mail.foo.com:465`.

As @natevw said in [Node.js Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262986/node-js-hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altnames):

> It would be better to first diagnose why the certificate is not authorizing and see if that could be fixed instead.

I would say my problem is that the internal docker-ip address is not in the certificate included.
So in my view I would say I have two options:

1. I could add somehow the ip address to the certificate
2. I could use somehow the localhost or domain name instead of the internal container id

But I sadly don't know how to achieve one of them.

If you need some configs or something like that please comment and I will edit this post.

Thanks in advance,
Michael