# Firebase Trigger E-Mail Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I am using the extension "Trigger E-Mail" in Firebase. When I try to send an e-mail and I get the following error:

> Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames

Does this mean the loaded certificate must contain my hostname to work? Sorry, I just have started studying certificates. If I am right then one solution would be to add my hostname into the certificate. As I am using a thirdparty mailprovider. UPDATE: The smtp server uses a shared certificate which doesnt include any other domain and it will never happen.

Similar posts using nodejs tell to set the following configuration:

```
{ rejectUnauthorized : false }
```

First I cannot set his configuration into the Extension, secondly I do not want to remove the security feature.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Considering that this error message is indeed relevant for all requests, are there any other scenarios within your application in which you send a request? Or are you certain that this has only started erroring when attempting to make use of the Trigger Email extension for Firebase?

Comment: I never saw this error before. It popped up when I started using the extension "Trigger E-Mail".

Comment: My best suggestion in this case would be to submit this issue to the firebase extensions [Git Issue Tracker](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues) as the Trigger E-Mail extension handles the routing of requests internally. Therefore it is unlikely that any changes on the user's end could cause a SSL certificate error as found in this case, as in this case you are only providing a email message for the extension to route accordingly.

Comment: Another possibility could be with the [SMTP server](https://sendgrid.com/blog/what-is-an-smtp-server/) utilized, as the extension is noted utilizing this server to relay email messages accordingly. In this case it is possible that this issue is similar to what is described in a [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28071485/12762626), on the end of the SMTP server.

Comment: I am contacting my smtps provider to add my domain into their certificate's altnames. I will update this post with a solution asap.