# Google recaptcha works in localhost but not example.com as a real site

Tags: javascript, node.js, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I have a code in Nodejs server which is using google recaptcha V3 to login a user. It's working perfectly with `https://localhost:4000/` but for some wired reason it doesn't work with my example.com website ?!

any suggestion to debug this?

I have added both localhost and example.com to the list of google recaptcha console.

**the code pauses before fetch, not going further seems like there is something wrong with fetch???**

```
function login(req, res, next) {
    const secret_key = config.recaptchaSecretKey;
    const token = req.body.token;
    const url = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secret_key}&response=${token}`;

    // the code pauses here not going further seems like there is something wrong with fetch???
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'post'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(google_response => {
        if(!google_response.success || google_response.score < 0.4) {
            return res.json({ success: false, error: "captcha verification failed" });
        }
        accountService.login(req.body) 
            .then(result => {
                res.json(result);
            })
            .catch(next);
    })
    .catch(error => res.json({ error }));
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "pauses before fetch"? how are you determining this pause?

Comment: does adding `mode: 'cors'` to the fetch options help? seems like it's possibly cors related

Comment: I think it might be the cors problem too, but `mode: 'cors'` didn't fix this

Comment: hmm in that case, it's back to the comment about first pinpointing exactly how it "pauses" as I'm a little unclear on where the error is occurring

Comment: It doesn't log anything after that point...

Comment: this is the error::: `reason: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: www.google.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:amazeservice.net, DNS:www.amazeservice.net`

Comment: Check this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262986/node-js-hostname-ip-doesnt-match-certificates-altnames

Some posts there report the same issue when switching from localhost.
There are some workarounds with security implications, but it looks like using http-proxy works best - depends on your requirements.